# Automating test cases with JBehave in an application in which UI is developed in SWING

Tags: swing, automation, automated-tests, bdd, jbehave

I want to automate some test cases in Jbehave in an application in which the UI is developed in SWING .
I don't want to do it with the UI (similar to Selenium) but want to call the functions of the UI(SWING) of the application .
Just want suggestions if I can use any other framework for the same or JBehave is a better option or if it is not feasible to use Jbehave for the same .

Thanks
Rahul